# How can I get objects from double related tables in MYSQL?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have a project with Java and I created tables using MySQL by phpmyadmin.
In the application we need to make basic messenger application
However I could not decide how should I make the class structure and also database structure.

I did that;
I have 2 tables.

```
User | id | ... | messageIds(varchar, it stores message ids which user received in comma seperated String)

Message | ownerId(foreign key for id) | ... |
```

In project I have 2 classes User and Message
User has ArrayList inbox
Message has User sender

I want to get user and message object from database and I need to fill the object constructors. However in that structure I need to get message with id to construct user, and also get user with id to construct message.

What are your advices ? 
Should I need to change the table structure ?
Is there any rational solution ?
Should I need to change class structure ?

Comment: Storing values as csv is very bad db design

Comment: I didnot know sql very well and I did not find another way

Comment: Read about normalization, one-to-Many relationship